# Check if a DIV element exists by its class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1">
    <div class="views-row views-row-2">
    <div class="views-row views-row-3">
    <div class="views-row views-row-4">
</div>
```

How can I in JavaScript/jQuery check whether the last `<div>` element (`<div class="views-row views-row-4">`) exist?

Some times, I just have 3 and others 4. When I just have 3, I would like to perform some CSS changes.

Comment: `if($(".views-row").length > 3) {`

Comment: saying on what element you want to perform the CSS changes , might help provide a better solution.

Comment: yea see that not closing? does not matter

Comment: @user3932702  It does matter.There is every chance that you may not get desired output because of mistakes like that. You want proper answers, ask proper questions .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look for the object and then check whether one was found:

```
if ($(".views-row-4").length) {
  // at least one element with class "views-row-4"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a div exist ,you can you can use the following Jquery snippet.

```
if( $('.your-class').length )
{
    //CODE IF DIV EXIST
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this like

```
$('.view-content').children().length
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you:

**JS**

```
var numClass = $(".views-row").length;
if(numClass == 3)
{
   /*Some Change in Your CSS*/
   $(".views-row").css("color","red");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check number of `div` inside the container `div`.

```
if ($('.view-content > div').length > 3) {
    // Do your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.length` in jquery

```
if($(".views-row").length == 3) {

}
```